# R parallel CPU affinity on Windows

Tags: r

**R** 2.14.0 or higher includes [R package **parallel**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) which provides support for parallel computation.

Under **Unix-likes**, this package provides a [facility for setting CPU affinity of child processes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mcaffinity.html).

Is there a means of setting CPU affinity of child processes when using the **R** package **parallel** on **Windows**?

Comment: I'd love to know if this is possible too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to set the CPU affinity of an R session on Windows.  This method requires PowerShell.  It sets the CPU affinity of the R session in which the command is executed.  Set `use.core` to a vector of length equal to the number of logical CPU cores, where each position indicates whether (`T`) or not (`F`) the R process should have affinity on that core.

```
use.core <- c(T, T, T, T)
affinity.mask <- sum(use.core*2^((1:length(use.core))-1))
shell(paste("PowerShell -Command \"& {(Get-Process -id ",Sys.getpid(),").ProcessorAffinity = ",affinity.mask,"}\"",sep=""))
```